# implicit rule vs explicit rule

Tags: makefile

I'm not understanding why when and why make will remake a file.

Implicit rule:

```
foo : foo.o bar.o
    cc -o foo foo.o bar.o $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Explicit rule:

```
foo.o: foo.p
```

Will the above explicit rule remake the foo.o?
Why and why not?

Comment: I think it will not, if `foo.o` exists it will not be remade.

Comment: Both rules are explicit, implicit rules are either pattern rules (contain `%`) or suffix rules (obsolete). Other than that I'm not sure what you are asking, rules alone don't "cause" a file to be remade, that depends on whether a target is out of date or not according to the dependency chain.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi:  In OP's question, `foo.o` is dependent on `foo.p`, and potentially is implicitly dependent on `foo.c`, etc.   So, if you make `foo`, then it will rebuild `foo.o` if -- foo.o does not exist, or if foo.p / foo.c are newer - thus it may build foo.o even if it exists..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @user657267, I'm not entirely clear what the question is, but let me try to walk you through it.

I'm assuming that you are either typing `make foo`, or that you are typing `make`, and that `foo:` is the default target (the target closest to the top of the makefile).

`foo` is dependent on `foo.o` and `bar.o`, so before it can make `foo`, it must first check those.   Make will first check `foo.o`.   This is dependent on `foo.p` according to your Makefile.

But, because you didn't specify a recipe in the `foo.o: foo.p` line, then you have simply generated a dependency, not a rule, so it will continue to look for other dependencies/rules.  Because an explicit rule was not specified to build `foo.o`, then make will search for an implicit rule that matches.

Let's say it finds the implicit rule `%.o: %.c` (which is enabled by default in make).   If there is a `foo.c`, then it will try to use this rule.   Because this rule also has a dependency on `%.c`, then `foo.c` is also considered a dependency.

`foo.o` is now dependent on `foo.c` and `foo.p`.  If either of these is newer than foo.o, or if foo.o does not exist, then it will be considered out of date, and make will run the recipe in the implicit rule.  Otherwise, it will consider foo.o as being up to date and not rebuild it.

If make does rebuild `foo.o`, then it will consider `foo` to be out of date, and it will rebuild `foo` as well.

There's a bunch of special cases that I didn't mention, such as how make decides which pattern rule applies, etc, but the jist is there.   You should read the makefile documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for more information on how make works.